# Weird syntax in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I found this lisp function while I was googling

```
(defun filter (lst items-to-filter)
   (cond ((null lst) nil)
         ((member (car lst) items-to-filter) #1=(filter (cdr lst) items-to-filter))
         (t (cons (car lst) #1#))))
```

It's just set difference, but this is the first time i see #1= and #1#, syntax. I think I understand what it means just by looking at the code, but I am not too sure. I think the #1= is used to label an expression so as not to retype it later when needed, one can just refer to it by #index#, in this case index=1. I was wondering if someone could shed some light on this. What are these constructs called, if there's a reference for them, and if they are widely used in modern lisp code. Thanks

Comment: Possible reference material: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dh.htm  It appears the 2nd `#` invokes the "reference to" macro.  I have no idea if use of this functionality is common.  Is use of lisp at all common?  :)

Comment: This is the sharpsign sharpsign reader macro, which gives the possibility to refer to a form previously read. For documentation, see section 2.4.8.16 of the Common Lisp hyperspec, e.g. at http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhp.htm

Comment: A simple `let' is usual here, to compute the filtered list just once.  I see no advantage to using this gymnastic instead, but I might be missing something.

Comment: @Drew Since the code is referenced from different branches it will be computed just once as is. I wouldn't have written it like above, but to get the same semantics with a let you would have to place the let after the null check, at which point an author might decide #1# is easier than re-factoring into nested conditionals.

Comment: "Easier" to do does not mean better code as a result.  It's not hard to nest conditionals, and it certainly would not make this code more difficult to understand! And yes, I understand that you, like I and most people, would not normally write code like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see it in written source code is very very unusual. Most of the time you see it in data. It is used to create or print shared data items in s-expressions. This way you can also read or print circular s-expressions.

You could use it for easier creation of repeated code, but usually one writes functions or macros for that. Functions have the advantage that they save code space - unless they are inlined.

```
CL-USER 3 > (pprint '(defun filter (lst items-to-filter)
                       (cond ((null lst) nil)
                             ((member (car lst) items-to-filter)
                              #1=(filter (cdr lst) items-to-filter))
                             (t (cons (car lst) #1#)))))

(DEFUN FILTER (LST ITEMS-TO-FILTER)
  (COND ((NULL LST) NIL)
        ((MEMBER (CAR LST) ITEMS-TO-FILTER)
         (FILTER (CDR LST) ITEMS-TO-FILTER))
        (T
         (CONS (CAR LST) (FILTER (CDR LST) ITEMS-TO-FILTER)))))
```

As you see above the printer does not print it that way. Why is that?
There is a global variable `*print-circle*` which controls it. For above example it was set to `NIL`. Let's change that:

```
CL-USER 4 > (setf *print-circle* t)
T

CL-USER 5 > (pprint '(defun filter (lst items-to-filter)
                       (cond ((null lst) nil)
                             ((member (car lst) items-to-filter)
                              #1=(filter (cdr lst) items-to-filter))
                             (t (cons (car lst) #1#)))))

(DEFUN FILTER (LST ITEMS-TO-FILTER)
  (COND ((NULL LST) NIL)
        ((MEMBER (CAR LST) ITEMS-TO-FILTER)
         #1=(FILTER (CDR LST) ITEMS-TO-FILTER))
        (T
         (CONS (CAR LST) #1#))))
```

So this shows that one can read and print such s-expressions in Common Lisp

Sharing some source code data structures is more common in computed code:

```
CL-USER 22 > (defmacro add-1-2-3 (n) `(,n 1 2 3))
ADD-1-2-3

CL-USER 23 > (walker:walk-form '(+ (add-1-2-3 4) (add-1-2-3 5)))
(+ (4 . #1=(1 2 3)) (5 . #1#))
```

Comment: One additional but rare use is to refer to a literal object for the purpose of EQness without creating a binding. e.g. as part of a macro definition `(lambda (#1=#.(gensym)) (declare (ignore #1#) ...)

Comment: Another rare but useful example is to refer back to the doc string of a function so we can print it as necessary:  (defun do-it (cmd &rest args) #1="This does it." (case cmd (:help (print #1#)) ...).